# Javascript Recursion inside class method (this behaviour)

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, tree, this

The problem lies inside toString function , this does not actualize the scope as the function calls itself: 
I need something to solve the problem , 'this' is the worst in javascript , i have implemented the exact data structure and function in python and it works... , i've tried binding and arrow functions , maybe you can help me out...
The expected result for the code down below :

```
1
|__2
   |__3
      |__4
         |__5
```

```
class Node {

    constructor(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = [];
        Node.nodes.push(this);
        this.index = Node.nodes.length;
    }

    addChild(node){
        node.parent = this;
        this.children.push(node);

    }

    getLevel(){
        let level = 0;
        while(this.parent){
            level+=1;
            this.parent = this.parent.parent;
        }
        //console.log('lvl',level);
        return level;
    }

     toString (){
        // console.log('lvl',this.getLevel());
        let prefix = " ".repeat(this.getLevel()*3);
        prefix += this.getLevel()===0 ? "" :"|__";
        console.log(prefix + this.index);

        if(this.children){
            for(let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
                this.children[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }

    pathToRoot(){
        return 0;
    }

}
Node.nodes = [];

const main = (()=>{

let root = new Node('root');
let kid1 = new Node('kid1');
let kid2 = new Node('kid2');
let kid3 = new Node('kid3');
let kid4 = new Node('kid4');

root.addChild(kid1);
kid1.addChild(kid2);
kid2.addChild(kid3);
kid3.addChild(kid4);

console.log('kid4 lvl :',kid4.getLevel())

root.toString(root);


})()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get error messages?

Comment: The function doesn't do what it is supposed to do , and no no errors of syntax.You can copy paste the code inside the browser console or node and see for yourself.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what it's supposed to do, and what it does now? Some example output and expected output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the parent of the parent in a loop. Instead use a variable for looping the parents.

```js
class Node {

    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = [];
        if (!Node.nodes) Node.nodes = [];
        Node.nodes.push(this);
        this.index = Node.nodes.length;
    }
   
    addChild(node) {
        node.parent = this;
        this.children.push(node);
    }

    getLevel() {
        let level = 0;
        let parent = this.parent;   // start with parent
        while (parent) {            // check value
            level += 1;
            parent = parent.parent; // assign parent
        }
        //console.log('lvl',level);
        return level;
    }

    toString() {
        // console.log('lvl',this.getLevel());
        let prefix = " ".repeat(this.getLevel() * 3);
        prefix += this.getLevel() === 0 ? "" : "|__";
        console.log(prefix + this.index);

        if (this.children) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
                this.children[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }

    pathToRoot() {
        return 0;
    }

}

const main = (() => {
  let root = new Node('root');
  let kid1 = new Node('kid1');
  let kid2 = new Node('kid2');
  let kid3 = new Node('kid3');
  let kid4 = new Node('kid4');

  root.addChild(kid1);
  kid1.addChild(kid2);
  kid2.addChild(kid3);
  kid3.addChild(kid4);

  console.log('kid4 lvl :', kid4.getLevel())

  root.toString(root);
console.log(root);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you , it works , but  why  ? isn't it tehnically the same ?

Comment: no. your original code overwrites the value of the node. later it `null`, the last value of the nested nodes and it lost its reference to the parents. by using another variable, the object reference remains intact and works as intended.

Comment: Basically i cut the branch right under my feet , pun intended , TY for explaining also.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it is not about the `this` mechanism. You lack a base case(so the recursive function will keep running forever). You need to think of in what situation the recursion should end.

```
toString (){
        // think of your base case here. Examples are as below
        // should it be prefix === ""?
        // should it be when length of prefix smaller or greater than specific length 


        let prefix = " ".repeat(this.getLevel()*3);
        prefix += this.getLevel()===0 ? "" :"|__";
        console.log(prefix + this.index);

        if(this.children){
            for(let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
                this.children[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The function will stop executing once it gets to the leaves , because they have no children.
PS: have you tried running the code ?